# Как настроить в VSCode автоматическое перемещение на строку, где производишь отмену/повтор действия которое добавлено через внешний редактор

Tags: visual-studio-code, редактор, google-chrome-devtools

**Здравствуйте!**

Как настроить в Visual Studio Code автофокус (автоматически перемещаться) на строку в которой производишь отмену/повтор (ctrl+z/ctrl-y) команды/действия, для тех изменений, которые внесены через внешние редакторы?

Пример: Сейчас если работаешь в VSCode и вносишь какие-либо правки (например в CSS), не важно переместился ли ты вверх или вниз по файлу, при отмене действия ты автоматически перемещаешься в строку в которой происходит отмена, т.е. все как и должно быть.

Если данный CSS файл параллельно подключен через Dev Tools (workspace) и ты вносишь в него изменения прямо в браузере, то отменить действия в VSCode можно, но без автофокуса (условно нажимаешь ctrl+z и где-то там, что-то отменяется сам процесс не виден), поэтому чтобы проверить все ли действия ты отменил, приходится скролить/переходить на нужную строку в ручную, а это очень не удобно.

Подскажите пожалуйста какие настройки нужно сделать, чтобы гарантированно автоматически перемещаться в ту строку в которой что-либо изменяется в данный момент времени.

Также подскажите возможно есть какой-то плагин для VSCode с историей/журналом действий, где можно откатится сразу например на 40-50 шагов кликнув по нужному значению в истории (по аналогии как это сделано в некоторых текстовых или графических редакторах). Или возможно это есть в штатных возможностях VSCode?

**Благодарю за ответ!**